# Share the generic type with nested classes

Tags: c#, inner-classes

I am getting a compile error on the following code (where I call _Context.OuterMethod(this)):

> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from TestApp.Outer<T>.Inner<T> to TestApp.Outer<T>.Inner<T>

Given the relationship between the classes shouldn't this work?

```
public class Outer<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public Outer()
    {
        _InnerObject = new Inner<T>(this);
    }

    private void OuterMethod(Inner<T> myInnerObject)
    {
        /* do something */
    }


    private Inner<T> _InnerObject; public Inner<T> InnerObject
    { 
        get { return _InnerObject; } 
    }


    public class Inner<T>
        where T : struct
    {
        Outer<T> _Context;

        public Inner(Outer<T> theContext)
        {
            _Context = theContext;
        }

        bool _SomeProperty;
        public bool SomeProperty
        {
            get { return _SomeProperty; }
            set
            {
                if(value != _SomeProperty)
                {
                    _SomeProperty = value;

                    _Context.OuterMethod(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inner's `T` has no relation to Outer's `T`.

Comment: But since the `Inner` type is nested you could just omit the type prameter declaration of it, and instead just use the `T` declared by the `Outer` type.

Comment: Put it as `public class Inner {...}` and use `T` from outer declaration

Comment: @bassfader you are very correct... im banging my head with generics trying to grasp

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, this code now works as I expected

```
public class Outer<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public Outer()
    {
        _InnerObject = new Inner(this);
    }

    private void OuterMethod(Inner myInnerObject)
    {
        /* do something */
    }

    private Inner _InnerObject; public Inner InnerObject
    { 
        get { return _InnerObject; } 
    }

    public class Inner
    {
        Outer<T> _Context;

        public Inner(Outer<T> theContext)
        {
            _Context = theContext;
        }

        bool _SomeProperty;
        public bool SomeProperty
        {
            get { return _SomeProperty; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _SomeProperty)
                {
                    _SomeProperty = value;

                    _Context.OuterMethod(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```